# MySQL have system tables for mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I am coming from SQL Server where I can find almost anything I need about a database under the systems db's. I am wondering if MYSQL has a system table that will show when the last time a database was backed up via mysqldump.

The whole reason I am asking this is I am trying to create a dashboard/report (SSRS) to show when backups complete or fail. Right now we only get alerted via email so if there is another way I am all ears

Comment: All the system information is in the `mysql` database. AFAIK, there's nothing related to `mysqldump`.

Comment: You could create your own table, and wrap your `mysqldump` commands in a script that updates the table.

Comment: I was afraid of that answer but I think creating my own table may be the only option.